# Interpret result of corrcoef(X) function

Tags: matlab, matrix, correlation

I have these four variables:

```
Class1 
Class2
Class3 
Class4
```

Each of them is a matrix.

They are inside a matrix `X`.

```
X = [[Class1]' [Class2]' [Class3]' [Class4]']
```

I apply a `corrcoef` function to `X`.

```
B = corrcoef(X)
```

to obtain the result:

```
B = 1.0000   -0.2392    0.9533    0.6903
   -0.2392    1.0000   -0.1272    0.4267
    0.9533   -0.1272    1.0000    0.6971
    0.6903    0.4267    0.6971    1.0000
```

But I don't know what this means. How can I interpret these values and what do they mean?

I can't find help in MATLAB's help documentation.

Comment: Here's the MATLAB manual page: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/corrcoef.html

Comment: If you feel I have answered the question, then please click the tick mark next to my answer. If you are unsatisfied with my answer then let me know and perhaps I can improve it. Cheers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you know the definition of a sample correlation coefficient then the answer is simple.

Since `B` is 4 by 4, I think I can safely assume that `Classz` is a row vector of observations on some random variable, and that you have 4 such row vectors. Thus X is a N by 4 matrix, with columns corresponding to random variables 1 to 4, and rows corresponding to observations on the random variables.

If you check the documentation in the link provided by Mark Elliot, you'll note that this implies that `X` has the correct orientation for applying the `corrcoef` function.

The output of `corrcoef` is the sample correlation matrix. It is 4 by 4 since you have 4 random variables (columns of `X`) to start with. The diagonals of this matrix correspond to each random variables correlation with itself (hence they're all equal to 1). The off-diagonals correspond to sample correlation coefficients between the random variables. That is, the number in element (2, 3) is the sample correlation coefficient between random variable 2 and 3 (ie column 2 and 3 of `X`). Since the sample correlation coefficient between 2 and 3 is the same as between 3 and 2, `B` is thus symmetric by construction.

Hopefully this clears it up. If the problem is that you don't know what a correlation coefficient is, then SO is probably not the right forum. Maybe do some research of your own and then if you still have a question post it to Math Exchange.

Comment: Hello Colin. Thanks for your reply. I think that my problem is that I need correlation, but don't know very well what is it. Can you explain me in resume what is correlation? Thanks for your explanation of the results. Very good. :)

Comment: @RicardoFilipe Alas, Stack Overflow is not the right forum for a straight maths question. Also, I can't really give a better explanation than [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_product-moment_correlation_coefficient). Or (for something simpler) [this](http://www.dmstat1.com/res/TheCorrelationCoefficientDefined.html). Sorry, I can't do more than this or I will be setting a bad precedent by answering math questions on a computer programming forum. I hope you understand. If you feel I've answered the programming side of things, then please click the tick mark next to my answer. Cheers.